# Kiosk mode for tv app

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, device-policy-manager, cosu

I've integrated kiosk mode for an android app that runs on TV using http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/. As per the kiosk mode only my app is opening on boot completion.But the problem is it is allowing home and back button through remote that escapes my app from homescreen.I want to show my app only in the device.As per customer requirements user should not allowed to open any other apps.Only one app should run on the TV screen.How to do it?

Comment: There are a number of off-the-shelf solutions out on the market that lock down an Android environment (Google for `Android kiosk software`.) I'd explore one of those, since there are many ways that someone can escape your application. (Full disclosure: my company makes one of those solutions.)

Comment: @Daniel did you find any solution?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, I have installed one APK to control Kiosk mode, it says clearly that Smart Tv's don't support Kiosk Mode. In one, I have managed to turn on Kiosk mode but there is a notification saying the app is pinned which need user interaction to hide.

Comment: @W.M. Did you found any solution for android TV?